# Как в данном случае можно все count отправить одним запросом?

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin

```
fun <T : IContainer, R: BaseFilterGroup> MongoTemplate.filtersByContainer(
    filterIds: Array<String>?,
    filterType: String,
    containerClass: Class<T>,
    filterClass: Class<R>) {
val filters = findOne(Query(Criteria.where("type").`is`(filterType)), filterClass) ?: return

filters.filters
        .flatMap { it.items }
        .forEach { item ->
            item.count = this.count(
                    Query(Criteria
                            .where("filterIds")
                            .all((filterIds ?: emptyArray()).plus(item.id).toList())),
                    containerClass)
                    .toInt()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Я не уверен, но что если затолкать запросы в массив, а затем на основе массива создать zip-запрос. Это точно позволяет объъеденить несколько запросов в пакет, но как упаковать все в цикле я точно не знаю.

```
Observable.zip(firebase.fetchUserById(auth.currentUser?.uid!!),
        firebase.fetchAssociates(auth.currentUser?.uid!!),
        firebase.fetchPomodoro(auth.currentUser?.uid!!),{user, associates, pomodoro ->
    println("000000000000000002")

    user
}).subscribe({
    println("000000000000000003  " + it.getName())
})
```